# Hints for solving this matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

\begin{equation}
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
    1    & 0   & 1 \\
    0    & 2   & 1 \\
    0    & 1   & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} \\
\end{equation}

Solve the matrix equation:
\begin{equation}
XA=A+2X
\end{equation}
Where $X$ is a matrix. If I have understood the problem correctly $X$ is $3x3$.

I was thinking maybe I could use the Identity matrix and get something like:
\begin{equation}
X=(A+2X)A^{-1}
\end{equation}
I would like some tips on how to solve this, thanks.

Comment: $2X = X\times 2\times I$, which you can use to factor out the $X$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Advance as

$$ XA=A+2X \implies X(A-2I) =A \implies X = A(A-2I)^{-1}. $$